# Why do the modulo operation result take the dividend's type instead of the divisor's type?

Tags: java, scala, math

Why the result of the modulo operation `a % b` has the same type than `a` instead of the `b` type?

The remainder after a division **never** is going to be higher than the divisor, so the type of the result will fit in the divisor's type. So in `a % b`, the result is going to fit in the `b`'s type.

So if `b` is an `Int`, the result should be `Int` as well. Why is it a `Long`?

Example:

```scala
val a: Long = Long.MaxValue
val b: Int = 10

a % b
```

Result:

```
a: Long = 9223372036854775807
b: Int = 10

res0: Long = 7
```

In the `res0`, I was expecting an `Int`.

I asked the same in the [Scala contributors](https://contributors.scala-lang.org/t/is-the-modulo-operation-signature-in-sync-with-the-mathematical-definition/3868) forum to be able to follow a conversation.

Comment: It's because of implicit casting type before division. Before evaluation, b will cast to Long and after all result of a % b will be Long type. Remainder never higher than divisor but in Scala compiler can't do operations such as division btw different data types.

Comment: It's may be because Java do it (and because your Scala compiler use JVM). This code is **invalid**: `int c = ((long)23) % 35;` Why Java do it, I don't know:)

Comment: You can add `java` tag, and make little change in question.

Comment: Hi Mikhail. Java tag added

Comment: It's an interesting question, I'd be curious to know the answer too. Maybe it's simply because it's easier to have one rule for all binary operators.

Comment: I explained why (I believe) Java does it in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, Scala follows Java here. And Java follows C. And C actually has a good reason for this! Namely:

1. it has separate signed and unsigned types;
2. result of `a % b` has the same sign as `a` (e.g. `-10 % 3` is `-1`). (This wasn't required in older C versions, but always allowed.)

So if `-10` above is `signed long` and `3` is `unsigned int`, then the result can't be the same type as the divisor because it must be signed. It couldn't be `signed int` either, because instead of `3` we could have something which fits into `unsigned int` but not `signed int`. Applying the same rules as for other arithmetical operators gives reasonable return type, so that's what C does.

Comment: We can not apply this rule to Scala, because Scala does not have unsigned numerics types. Maybe the only exception is Char, but the signature for this case could be different.

Comment: Again, the reason _Scala_ does this is simply compatibility with Java.

Comment: Do you know if Scala is using directly the Java operator, or it is a wrapper around? I mean, don't make sense to cast the response to the right type before to return it?

Comment: It looks like it is translated into Java byte code directly, so adding casting will add a performance penalty.

Comment: JVM bytecode has `irem` which takes two `Int` and returns `Int` and `lrem` which takes two `Long` and returns `Long`. So yes, your desired signature would require an extra cast which can't generally be optimized out. On the other hand, it already requires one cast (`b` from `Int` to `Long`) and nobody seems to have a problem with that.

Answer (score 1):

Because it resolves to the following overloaded version of [`Long.%`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/049417ee2a0671f06488f755b3a9c7dc6a048dfa/src/library/scala/Long.scala#L434)

```
def %(x: Int): Long
```

where we see the return type is `Long`.

Comment: So why this signature? If x is Int, the response should be Int as well. Why Long?

Comment: @angelcervera `a % b` desugars to something like `a.%(b)` where we see `%` method is called on `Long` instance `a` which has a method precisely matching the type of passed in argument `b` which is of type `Int`. Because this resolved method has return type of `Long` it will be indeed `Long` that is returned.

Comment: I understand how is resolved.  My question is why this signature.  I think that the right signature should be def %(×:Int):Int